# Trigonometry: Unusual Double-Angle Identities

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing

Here are some trig identities:

> $$\begin{align}
> \sin 2a &= \frac{\tan 2a \tan a}{\tan 2a-\tan a}\\[4pt]
> \tan 2a &= \frac{2\sin^2a}{\sin 2a - \tan a }\\[4pt]
> \tan 2a &= \tan a \left(\frac{1}{\cos 2a}+1\right)\\[4pt]
> \cos 2a &= \frac{\tan a}{\tan 2a-\tan a}
> \end{align}$$

Question:
Prove those identities.

Comment: I tried many things but i cant

Comment: I'll help you with one but you should at least be able to do the rest using that one example.

Comment: Okay i will do rest

Answer (score 3):

I'll help you with the first two-try to do the rest on your own
$$\sin 2\alpha = \frac{\tan 2 \alpha \tan \alpha}{\tan 2 \alpha - \tan \alpha}$$

$$RHS = \frac{\frac{\sin 2 \alpha}{\cos 2 \alpha}\frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}}{\frac{\sin 2 \alpha}{\cos 2 \alpha}-\frac{\sin \alpha}{\cos \alpha}} = \frac{\frac{\sin 2 \alpha \sin \alpha}{\cos 2 \alpha \cos \alpha}}{\frac{\sin 2 \alpha \cos \alpha-\cos 2 \alpha \sin \alpha}{\cos 2 \alpha\cos \alpha}}$$

$$= \frac{\sin 2 \alpha\sin \alpha}{\sin 2 \alpha \cos \alpha-\cos 2 \alpha \sin \alpha}$$

$$\text{Note that:} \ \sin 2 \alpha \cos \alpha-\cos 2 \alpha \sin \alpha = \sin(2\alpha -\alpha) = \sin \alpha$$

$$RHS  = \frac{\sin 2 \alpha\sin \alpha}{\sin \alpha} =  \sin 2 \alpha = LHS$$

Second question (just realised its $a$ rather than $\alpha$):

$$\tan 2a = \frac{2\sin^2a}{\sin 2a - \tan a} $$

$$ RHS = \frac{2 \sin^2 a}{\sin 2 a- \frac{\sin a }{\cos a}} = \frac{2 \sin^2 a}{\frac{\sin 2a\cos a - \sin a }{\cos a}}$$

$$= \frac{2 \sin^2a\cos a}{\sin a( 2\cos^2 a - 1)}$$

$$ = \frac{2\sin a\cos a}{2\cos^2 a - 1}= \frac{\sin 2 a}{\cos 2a} = \tan 2 a = LHS$$

I'm sure you can use a similar method to prove the rest.

Comment: Please prove any one again please!!!

Comment: Please prove any other one

Comment: @RAM, ok, I'll do a second one.

Comment: @RAM, I've added one more proof to my answer. Now try to do the rest yourself-at least show your thoughts perhaps by editing your question to add some attempt.

Answer (score 0):

first & second identities have already been proved in the above answer hence the rest of the identities can be easily proved as follows

3. $$\tan 2a=\tan a\left(\frac{1}{\cos 2a}+1\right)$$ 
   $$RHS=\frac{\sin a}{\cos a}\left(\frac{1+\cos 2a}{\cos 2a}\right)$$
   $$=\frac{\sin a}{\cos a}\left(\frac{1+2\cos^2a-1}{\cos 2a}\right)$$
   $$=\frac{\sin a}{\cos a}\left(\frac{2\cos^2a}{\cos 2a}\right)$$
   $$=\frac{2\sin a\cos a}{\cos 2a}=\frac{\sin 2a}{\cos 2a}=\tan 2a=LHS$$
4. $$\cos 2a=\frac{\tan a}{\tan 2a-\tan a}$$
   $$RHS=\frac{\tan a}{\tan 2a-\tan a}$$
   $$=\frac{\frac{\sin a}{\cos a}}{\frac{\sin 2a}{\cos2 a}-\frac{\sin a}{\cos a}}$$
   $$=\frac{\sin a\cos 2a}{\sin 2a\cos a-\cos 2a\sin a}$$
   $$=\frac{\sin a\cos 2a}{\sin (2a-a)}$$
   $$=\frac{\sin a\cos 2a}{\sin a}=\cos 2a=LHS$$